# javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence

Tags: jsf, jpa, persistence

for a project I m working on I m using JPA and JSF on Eclipse. Initially I developed the data layer( the access in the database) and it works fine. But  when I integrated it with the JSF project and tried to connect to the db via a bean I m getting the following exception:

com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl processAction
SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence

Specifically it crashes when it tries to get the entitymanager factory

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ResearchManagement.Data");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
```

I have included all required libraries, included javax/persistence. 
I cannot understand why I get this error. 
Below you can see the full exception stack and also an image of the libraries that I include.

Could someone please tell me what I m doing wrong? I have also looked at other similar questions posted but couldnt solve my problem. 
Thank you guys

```
 SEVERE: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at org.ResearchManagement.Handlers.UserHandler.getAllUsers(UserHandler.java:31)
    at org.tutorial.LoginBean.authenticate(LoginBean.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
11 Οκτ 2012 6:55:10 μμ com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{loginBean.authenticate}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginBean.authenticate}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
    at org.ResearchManagement.Handlers.UserHandler.getAllUsers(UserHandler.java:31)
    at org.tutorial.LoginBean.authenticate(LoginBean.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those JAR files need to be dropped in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, not to be manually added in *Build Path* property of the project.

Undo every single change which you ever made in *Build Path* property of the project (recreating the project might be easier) and place the JAR files which your webapp depends on (and isn't already provided by the container itself) straight in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder without fiddling/modifying any IDE project setting.

Comment: I did what you proposed but still I get the same error :( . I even placed the libraries in the Tomcat lib folder but still nothing.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError is due to lack of class definiton at run time

I had a very similar problem but I was using Jdeveloper.
When I added an external library, I forgot to check the option "deployed by default" so I believe that added jar files might not be deployed before running.

I don't know if there is an option as "deployed by default" in eclipse but I'd suggest you to look for something similar while adding a library